# Java: Finding Percent Difference

Tags: java, for-loop, percentage, difference

I am trying to figure out how to find the percent difference between the original (no space) string of text and the disemvoweled (no space) string of text. I am attempting to do this by using the equation ((newAmount-reducedAmount)/reducedAmount) but I am having no luck and am ending up with a value of zero, as shown below.

Thank you!

My Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prog5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the disemvoweling utility!"); // Initially typed "disemboweling" xD
        System.out.print("Enter text to be disemvoweled: ");
        String inLine = console.nextLine();
        String vowels= inLine.replaceAll("[AEIOUaeiou]", ""); // RegEx for vowel control
        System.out.println("Your disemvoweled text is: " + vowels); // Prints disemvoweled text

    // Used to count all characters without counting white space(s)
    int reducedAmount = 0;
    for (int i = 0, length = inLine.length(); i < length; i++) {
        if (inLine.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            reducedAmount++;
        }
    }

    // newAmount is the number of characters on the disemvoweled text without counting white space(s)
    int newAmount = 0;
    for (int i = 0, length = vowels.length(); i < length; i++) {
        if (vowels.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            newAmount++;
        }
    }

    int reductionRate = ((newAmount - reducedAmount) / reducedAmount); // Percentage of character reduction


    System.out.print("Reduced from " + reducedAmount + " to " + newAmount + ". Reduction rate is " + reductionRate + "%");

    }
}
```

My output: (Test string is without quotes: "Testing please")

```
Welcome to the disemvoweling utility!

Enter text to be disemvoweled: Testing please

Your disemvoweled text is: Tstng pls

Reduced from 13 to 8. Reduction rate is 0%
```

Comment: Because you use `int`, please change `int reductionRate = ((newAmount - reducedAmount) / reducedAmount); ` to `dobule reductionRate = ((double)(newAmount - reducedAmount) / reducedAmount); `

Comment: @Aramza, I know that I am tooo late for comments on your question. I was looking for something else and landed into this question.

Just wondering whether your formula is correct?
e.g. if newAmount = 10 and reducedAmount = 8, then reduction rate should be 20% And by your formula it comes as (10-8)*100/8 = 25 %

shouldn't it be (newAmount - reducedAmount) * 100 / newAmount ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used an integer data type while calculating percentage difference while performing integer division. You need to type cast one of the variables on the right hand side of the equation to perform double division and then store them in double. The reason for doing this is java integer type can't hold the real numbers. 
Also, multiple it by 100 to get the percentage.

```
double reductionRate = 100 * ((newAmount - reducedAmount) / (double)reducedAmount);
```

If you want a fraction between 0 and 1, then

```
double reductionRate = ((newAmount - reducedAmount) / (double)reducedAmount);
```

Comment: I blanked out and didn't put together to just multiply by -100, I should have taken a break instead of getting frustrated. Thank you though, this makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

Your formula gives you a value between zero and one.

An integer cannot hold fractions so it always shows zero.

Multiply by 100 to get a regular percentage value.

```
int reductionRate = 100*(newAmount - reducedAmount) / reducedAmount; // Percentage of character reduction
```

Comment: @NirajPatel Why should it be a double? If he wants a rounded number between 0 and 100 it does not have to be a double. The OP expressed no interest in a fractional part.